# Phpmyadmin Edit Privileges for root | 127.0.0.1

Tags: phpmyadmin, root

| 127.0.0.1 | root|

I *Edit Privileges* for 127.0.0.1 | root and change password (it happens because of my misunderstanding).

Now on my web is everything ok. But I am afraid that I do not see problem.

Q1: Should I change old passwords for new one in any *.php files?
Q2: Editing PW for 127.0.0.1 | root is the same that editing PW for localhost?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to change password - while connecting to DB give the new password
2. Yes Editing password for 127.0.0.1 is same as Editing password for localhost.